# javascript fire method before or after another method is called

Tags: javascript, events, prototype-programming

I would like to know what are the common approach to make this concept works:

```
function Abc () {
  var beforeMethod = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  };

  this.before('bob ana', beforeMethod);
}

Abc.prototype.ana   = function () { console.log('ana'); }

Abc.prototype.bob   = function () { console.log('bob'); }

Abc.prototype.maria = function () { console.log('maria'); }

//

var abc = new Abc();

abc.ana();
```

It's supposed to call `beforeMethod` before `bob` or `ana` is called.

Comment: This question is extremely vague. Are you trying to call abc.bob before abc.ana? What is the output that you are looking for?

Comment: What is `e` supposed to be?

Comment: Hi, `e` should the event itself, I imagine for example `e.name` would returns `ana` in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly :

need to be tested and securised, but i think it do the trick !
I haven't understood what your `e` mean so i put the called method name in it !

```js
var el = document.getElementById('debug');
var $l = function(val) {
    console.log(val);
    el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + '<div>' + val + '</div>';
  };
//___________________________________________________________________

var Before = function( methods , func , context){
  methods.split(' ').map(function(m){
    var ori = context[m];
    if(ori){
      context[m] = function(){
        func.call(context , m);
        return ori.apply(context , arguments);
      };
    } 
  });
};

var Abc = function () {
  var beforeMethod = function (e) {
    $l('from beforeMethod : ' + e);
  };

  Before('bob ana ', beforeMethod , this);
};
    
    Abc.prototype.ana   = function () { $l('from ana '); };
    
    Abc.prototype.bob   = function () { $l('from bob '); };
    
    Abc.prototype.maria = function () { $l('from maria '); };
    
    var abc = new Abc();
    
    abc.ana();
    abc.maria();
    abc.bob();
```

```html
<div id='debug'>Debug
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do this is to save the old prototype function in a property.

```
function Abc() {
    this.oldana = this.prototype.ana;
    this.oldbob = this.prototype.bob;
    this.prototype.ana = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        this.oldana();
    }
    this.prototype.bob = function(e) {
        console.log(e);
        this.oldbob();
    }
}
```